# How to get selected value in typescript react js from react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I followed a tutorial to use react-select dropdown in my react js , typscript project. I was able to work with the code below, but I am new to react js and typescript. how do i get the value of the selected in the code below. say, in the selectHandler function , i want to compare selected value as such

```
`
  if ( this.state.someValue == 'b") 
`
```

I get an error because, this.state.someValue is not a string . how to extract the just the value after user selects it.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Select, {ValueType} from 'react-select';
 
interface SomeState { someValue: ValueType<{ value: string; label: string; }>; }
 
const opt = [{ value: 'a', label: 'awesome' }, { value: 'b', label: 'boring' }];
 
export class someClass extends React.Component<any, SomeState> {
 constructor(props: any) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { someValue: null}
 }
 
 public render(): JSX.Element {
  return ( <>
    <Select value={this.state.someValue} onChange={this.selectHandler} options={opt} />
  </> );}

 private selectHandler (selectedFromPlace: ValueType<{ value: string; label: string; }>): 
  void {
        this.setState({ someValue});
    };
}`
```

Comment: Which version of react-select are you using?

Comment: version 16.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value is of type object with the keys `label` and `value` . To extract only the value from your selected option .

In your select handler you are getting the selected option in the name `selectedFromPlace` .

So to get only the value you need to do `selectedFromPlace.value`

Comment: nope , still not working , when I try selectedFromPlace?.value, i get error Property 'value' does not exist on type '{value : string; label: string;} | OptionsType<{value: string; label:string}>

Comment: my guess is , i will have to cast that object to to type of OptionsType , may be

Comment: where are you trying to access the value ? . It seems to work for me . Here is the sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-frog-1wp26?file=/src/App.tsx